# setAngularVelocity does not work

Tags: game-engine

I run the following code in Blender Game Engine:

ball.setAngularVelocity((0,0,0),1) #or ball.setAngularVelocity((0,0,0),0)
print(ball.worldAngularVelocity)

So I expect to see Vector (0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000) at each iteration, but the output looks like the following:

Vector (0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000)

Vector (-1.1090, -0.8872, 0.1430)

Vector (-0.8303, -0.6629, -0.4372)

Vector (5.1094, 1.9519, 0.2987)

Could someone help me how I can set the angular velocity to zero?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. It is a bug in Blender and it does not accept (0,0,0) as angular velocity. It should be a small number instead of 0 for example (0.00001, 0.00001, 0.00001)

Comment: It is not a bug. It is a "feature". This comes from the motion actuator. 0.0 values are interpreted as "no change". This allows to combine different motion vectors. While this feels nice in the GUI it is pretty annoying in Python.